# Initializing Map with constant values (java 8)

Tags: java-8, functor

Given a list:

```
List<V> myList=....;
```

How do I initialize a map where the items from the list are the keys, and each entry in the map has a constant value.
For example, if I want to map each item to an integer, I could do:

```
Map<V,Integer> myMap=...;
for(V v : myList) myMap.put(v, 1);
```

Using a functor, I came up with the following:

```
 Map<V,Integer> myMap=myList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(listItem->listItem , listItem->Integer.valueOf(1)));
```

Is there a more elegant way (concise) way using a functor?

Comment: Your solution doesn't look so bad.

Comment: This is cleaner: 
Map<V,Integer> myMap=myList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity() , listItem->1.0));